# Allocating memory to array of strings in c

Tags: c, memory, struct

I'm in the process of creating a hash table. I'm using a struct for the capacity, number of keys, frequencies and the keys themselves. Here is my code for initializing the struct:

```
htable htable_new(int capacity) {

  htable result = emalloc(sizeof *result);
  result->capacity = capacity;
  result->frequencies = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->frequencies[0]);
  result->keys = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->keys[0]);
  result->frequencies = 0;
  result->keys = NULL;

  return result;
}
```

Now, from my understanding, a char** array is a pointer to an array of pointers (of type char)? So when I allocate memory, would it be correct to use keys[0]? I assume that this
just represents the size of the char pointer? Which leads to my next question of when I
actually set the keys in the array (which is obviously in another function) would I just
allocate memory to each index by the size of the string I input before storing it?

i.e. `h->keys[index] = emalloc(sizeof(str)`

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `emalloc` is a valid macro or function,

The calls

```
result->frequencies = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->frequencies[0]);
result->keys = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->keys[0]);
```

are OK. However, the next two lines:

```
result->frequencies = 0;
result->keys = NULL;
```

immediately cause memory leaks. I don't know why you have them. They should be removed.

Assuming `str` is of type `char*` or `char const*`, the line

```
h->keys[index] = emalloc(sizeof(str));
```

won't allocate the necessary amount of memory for `h->key[index]`. That will allocate enough memory to hold only a `char*`. You need:

```
h->keys[index] = emalloc(strlen(str)+1);
strcpy(h->keys[index], str);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply I used: result->frequencies = 0; and result->keys = NULL; because I wanted to set all elements equal to 0 and NULL respectively. How do I go about that?

Comment: You can use `calloc`.